# BackboneJS Display multiple collections in one <ul>-Element

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone-layout-manager

I would like to know if it's possible to diplay multiple collections inside one `<ul>`-element?

for example when I have multiple views, in each view I have a collection like this:

```
Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return '/path/to/JSON/file';
    }
});
```

Now I want to display all Collections inside the same `<ul>`-element so that in my frontend it would give me the output

```
<ul>
   <li>Data from Collection 1</li>
   <li>Data from Collection 1</li>
   <li>Data from Collection 2</li>
   <li>Data from Collection 2</li>
   <li>Data from Collection 3</li>
   <li>Data from Collection 3</li>
</ul>
```

Is that possible? If yes then how?

Thanks in advance...

**[EDIT]**

Ok, so in my mainView I have:

```
Artist.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'artistchannel',
    beforeRender: function() {

      var artistinstagramCollection = new ArtistInstagram.ArtistInstagramCollection();
      artistinstagramCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
      this.insertView('.socialMedia', new ArtistInstagram.View({collection:artistinstagramCollection}));
      artistinstagramCollection.fetch();

      var artisttwitterCollection = new ArtistTwitter.ArtistTwitterCollection();
      artisttwitterCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
      this.insertView('.socialMedia', new ArtistTwitter.View({collection: artisttwitterCollection}));
      artisttwitterCollection.fetch();

      var artistfacebookCollection = new ArtistFacebook.ArtistFacebookCollection();
      artistfacebookCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
      this.insertView('.socialMedia', new ArtistFacebook.View({collection: artistfacebookCollection}));
      artistfacebookCollection.fetch();
```

Like mentioned before, each Collection is bound to its own view:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var ArtistInstagram = App.module();

    ArtistInstagram.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: 'instagram',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render)
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.collection ? this.collection.toJSON() : [];
        }
    });
    ArtistInstagram.ArtistInstagramCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return '/myproject/index.php/api/social_feeds/instagram/' + this.artist_id;
        }
    });

    return ArtistInstagram;
}
```

**The same above goes for Twitter and Facebook. So I have 3 modules.**

Then in the template `artistchannel` there is a section where I have:

```
<div class="socialMediaDiv">
    <ul class="socialMedia"></ul>
 </div>
```

And my HandlebarsJS-HTML template looks like:

```
{{#each this}}
<li>
<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{title}}" /></a>
<section class="ip">
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    <h3>
        <time class="timeago" datetime="{{pubDate}}"></time>
        {{type}}
    </h3>
</section>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

When I do it like this it generates 3 `<li>`-elements, so the structure is like:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <li>some results from collection 1</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </li>
   <li>
      <li>some results from collection 2</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </li>
   <li>
      <li>some results from collection 3</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong??

By the way, I'm using backbone's `layoutmanager`

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible. When you render the collection view, just append to the container element (`el` or `$el`) instead of replacing its html.

Comment: Hmm, I have forexample `tagName: 'ul'` and `template: 'sometemplate'` in each view. So I attach the collections to a specific template and not a specific `el`, so should I do something like `this.$el.append('#container')` if my container element would be `<div id="container">` ?