# BackboneJS How to merge collections

Tags: backbone.js

I asked this before [BackboneJS Display multiple collections in one <ul>-Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677149/backbonejs-display-multiple-collections-in-one-ul-element) but I can't get it to work and I'm starting getting really desperate so 
how can I merge these 3 collections and display them in the same `<ul>`?

```
define(['app','backbone','modules/artistInstagram', 'modules/artistTwitter',
'modules/artistFacebook'

], function (App, Backbone, ArtistInstagram, ArtistTwitter, ArtistFacebook) {

    var ArtistSocialMedia = App.module();

    ArtistSocialMedia.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        id: 'suptiles',
        beforeRender: function(){
            var artistinstagramCollection = new ArtistInstagram.ArtistInstagramCollection();
            artistinstagramCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.socialMedia', new ArtistInstagram.View({collection: artistinstagramCollection}));
            artistinstagramCollection.fetch();

            var artisttwitterCollection = new ArtistTwitter.ArtistTwitterCollection();
            artisttwitterCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.socialMedia', new ArtistTwitter.View({collection: artisttwitterCollection}));
            artisttwitterCollection.fetch();

            var artistfacebookCollection = new ArtistFacebook.ArtistFacebookCollection();
            artistfacebookCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.socialMedia', new ArtistFacebook.View({collection: artistfacebookCollection}));               
            artistfacebookCollection.fetch();

        }
    });

    return ArtistSocialMedia;
});
```

Right now, it clearly creates 3 views but I want to merge them into one collection. Please help!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you create a jsbin or jsfiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: the problem is that it creates `<ul><div><li>everything from collection1</li></div><div><li>everything from collection2</li></div><div><li>everything from collection3</li></div>` but I want it to be `<ul><li>everything from all collections</li></ul>`

Comment: You probably want to render a li for each item in your collection and append it to same ul, if you provide a fiddle or jsbin it would be easier to see what your doing wrong.

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want... hmm gonna see if I can create a fiddle... still new to this

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink it - since you're defining an element with dynamic content, it should be its own View. It's an unordered list, so the tag name must be `<ul>`. All you're doing is filling in the `<li>`'s, so the template isn't very complicated.

```
var collection1 = new WhateverCollection();
var collection2 = new WhateverCollection();
var collection3 = new WhateverCollection();

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function(){ 

        // define template
        var templateStr = '<% _.each(collection,function(model){ %>\
                               <li><%- model.name %></li>\
                           <% }); %>';

        // convert to function
        var template = _.template(templateStr);

        // for learning purposes, render each one individually
        var htmlFromFirst = template({ collection: collection1.toJSON() });
        var htmlFromSecond = template({ collection: collection2.toJSON() });
        var htmlFromThird = template({ collection: collection3.toJSON() });

        // set the html
        this.$el.html( htmlFromFirst  + htmlFromSecond + htmlFromThird );

        return this;
    }

});
```

Comment: Ok I still cant get it to work. Tried to merge your example with my actual code but without luck and I'm lost. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Anyone? By the way I'm using the `layoutmanager` so this solution will not work. Sorry for not mentioning before...This is starting to drive me crazy!